# CXF reversing order of JSON array in JAXRS service request

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, cxf, jax-rs

My client application is sending a JSON object containing an array to the web service which is JAXRS rest web service implemented using apache cxf version 3.0.1. On the server end, I am seeing the array contents reversed. When the server sends this data back to client again, I find the contents reversed again (in original order now) at the client end.

As far as I understand, key value pairs inside a JSON objects can lose the ordering but an array should hold the ordering of the objects.

Also, in my application, JAXB provider is configured as -

```
  <bean id="jaxbProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
    <property name="namespaceMap" ref="jsonNamespaceMap"/>
  </bean>
```

Please suggest, if the CXF JSONProvider can possibly reverse the order of objects in the array. Is it configurable and can be stopped?

Comment: Can you show any code of the server part?

Comment: no way `jackson` parser doing it. try to debug the client after the json parsing and before the message goes, and see if its in the right order. do it also in the server side.

Comment: Check your logic on both client & server. Jackson works perfectly and doesn't modify the order AFAIK.

Comment: I have updated the post based on the information I found from the server side code.

Comment: can you share the `jsonNamespaceMap` ?

Comment: @Udy It is `<util:map id="jsonNamespaceMap" map-class="java.util.Hashtable">
  </util:map>`

Comment: give this a try, add it to the `JSONProvider` properties:
 <property name="serializeAsArray" value="true"/>

Comment: if this won't work i'll switch to a different provider and check if it happens there as well. see this for more information on how to do it: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html